# Add new path to an existing map in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a World Map using D3. I am using D3 library and topojson library for it's creation.

Now, I want to draw a path of a county named "Turkana" in "Kenya".For that I am appending a new path retrieved from the geoJSON data of "Turkana" county to the existing Path of the WorldMap.
Like below

```
g.selectAll("path")
  .data(countries)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .attr("class", "feature")
  .on("click", clicked);

g.selectAll("path")
  .data(geoJSONKenyaTurkana.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d",path)
  .attr("class", "feature");
```

But nothing seems to be happening. I mean path of Turkana county is not drawn. Any help would be appreciated.

I have created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wSf7eqs3cTFhnMRghnPI?p=preview) for my current working code.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are not using the enter method correctly. When you add the countries, you use a selection:

`g.selectAll("path")`

As there are no paths yet, this is an empty selection. In general, when you assign data to a selection and use the `enter()` selection, the enter selection holds all the features that need to be created. In this case, as you have no features in your initial selection; therefore, using `.enter().append()` will create one feature for each item in the data array. This works great the first time when appending countries.

The second time you use the same selection (when trying to add the county), but this time that selection is not empty - you are selecting all the paths you just made (one for each country). The enter selection will be empty, no new features need to be made, you are just updating the data for the first path that was created.

This is visible if you comment two lines in your code:

```
g.selectAll("path")
    .data(geoJSONKenyaTurkana.features)
    //.enter().append("path")
    .attr("d",path)
    //.attr("class", "feature");
```

Shown in this [example using your map](https://plnkr.co/edit/og2KPAMhnUhPkYbTpu1n?p=preview), you can see that the county data just replaced the datum for Canada (you can't see the new datum for Canada(now Turkana) because it is behind Kenya since it was appended before Kenya in the initial append).

To make your approach work you need to use a null selection, you could use `d3.selectAll(null)` or `d3.selectAll(".ClassDoesNotExistYet")` (the latter option is slightly slower) etc. If the selection is empty, all items in the data array that need to be appended will be in the enter selection. See this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/m0COuITsooSrhW5DxkMf?p=preview) of your code as intended (I removed the mesh as it reduced visibility of the county for this demo).

Comment: Nice Explanation.Thanks a lot.